# If Runtime exception is thrown and then caught inside a method annotated with spring's @Transactional, cause the transaction to rollBack?

Tags: spring, postgresql

Suppose this is the service containing method serviceMethod.

```
@Transactional
public void serviceMethod {
    myMethod();
}

public void myMethod() {
    //some code
    try {
        //some more code that throws a runtime exception
    } catch(RuntimeException exception) {
       //do something -- no exceptions generated/thrown from here
    }
    //some more code
 }
```

Will this result in the transaction rolling back?
Also is the behaviour same for RuntimeException and the exceptions which extends RuntimeException ?

Comment: No it will not rollback, the exception is the trigger for rollback, but the transaction never sees it and thus will try to commit.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum for the clarification.